# Button click in kendo grid column firing onclick of whole row

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, onclick, kendo-grid

Our customer wanted a kendo grid where he can click anywhere on a row to open the corresponding detail page. I'm adding the rows like this:

```
const cols = [
    { field: "Date", title: "Date", template: "#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd), 'dd.MM.yyyy')#" },
    { field: "Title", title: "Title" },
    { field: "", command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }];

let grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: this.dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    columns: cols,
    editable: "detail"
}).data("kendoGrid");
grid.one("dataBound", this.onDataBound.bind(this));
```

And in my function `onDataBound()`:

```
const grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
$(grid.tbody).on("click", "tr", function (e) {
    const rowData = grid.dataItem(this);
    const URL = startInfo.ApplicationRoot + "SomeDetailPage?SomeId=" + rowData.get("SomeId");
    window.open(URL, '_blank');
});
```

This works perfectly as expected. However, as you see, I have a column with a delete button. Here is the problem. Whenever I click on the delete button, I'm getting the confirmation message ("Are you sure to delete [...]?") and actually *can* delete the row successfully, but the detail page of the row opens as soon as I click the button.

How can I let the row know that it shouldn't open the detail page when I click the delete button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I can check the `tagName` when binding the click function to the row:

```
$(grid.tbody).on("click", "tr", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == "TD") {
        const URL = startInfo.ApplicationRoot + "SomeDetailPage?SomeId=" + rowData.get("SomeId");
        window.open(URL, '_blank');
    }
});
```

When I click the button, `tagName` get either "SPAN" or "A". Everything outside the button results in "TD".

Answer (score 0):

You should use e.stopPropagation(); on delete button so it will not pass the event to the row also.

Comment: It's not the button that passes the deletion event to the row, it's the row that passes the page opening to the button too.